# Fetch Parameter Value From Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Using Angular, I have a function being called on click and I'm passing someValue to it.

Example:

```
<button (click)="callFoo(bar)">Click Me!</button>
```

Now, my TS code is something like this:

```
callFoo(gotInput){
    console.log("Print: ", this.someFormGroup.controls.gotInput.value)
}
```

I'm unable to provide the value fetched  to the console.log statement because it says 'Value is declared but its value is never read'.
How do I go about this?

Comment: Are you trying to access the value of the form control using the passed parameter ``gotInput``?

Comment: Yes, Im trying to access the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
callFoo(gotInput){
    console.log("Print: ", this.someFormGroup.controls[gotInput].value)
}
```